# how to delete part of string element of numpy array python

Tags: python, arrays, string, numpy

I have a large array with this format

```
a = np.array([['#define', 'name_1', '(value1) /*comment 1*/'],
              ['#define', 'name_2', '(value2) /*comment 2*/'],
              ['#define', 'name_3', '(value3) /*comment 3*/'],
              ['#define', 'name_4', '(value4) /*comment 4*/']])
```

the strings from column 3 have comments and I just need to keep that 'value' part which is inside parenthesis i.e. (0x123)
The output would look like this

```
[['#define', 'name_1', '(value1)'],
              ['#define', 'name_2', '(value2)'],
              ['#define', 'name_3', '(value3)'],
              ['#define', 'name_4', '(value4)']]
```

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: simply do `arr.astype('<U8')` will get you the first 8 characters from all strings in an array. This you can apply on the last column of your array, or if all other strings are shorter, then on complete array. Check my answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: use `.split()` to split `/*` and keep only the first part which is `value`

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i][2] = a[i][2].split("/*")[0].strip()
```

**Option 2**: use `re.sub()` to substitute the comment part that is surrounded by `\**\` with `""`

```
import re
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i][2] = re.sub(r"/\*.*\*/", "", a[i][2]).strip()
```

output:

```
array([['#define', 'name_1', '(value1)'],
       ['#define', 'name_2', '(value2)'],
       ['#define', 'name_3', '(value3)'],
       ['#define', 'name_4', '(value4)']], dtype='<U22')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex for extract `(value)` from `'(value1) /*comment 1*/'`.

For getting `(value)` with regex you should import `re` library in python.

```
import re
import numpy as np 

pattern = re.compile(r'\((.*?)\)')

a = np.array([['#define', 'name_1', '(val1) /*comment 1*/'],
              ['#define', 'name_2', '(val2) /*comment 2*/'],
              ['#define', 'name_3', '(val3) /*comment 3*/'],
              ['#define', 'name_4', '(val4) /*comment 4*/']])

for row in a:
    new = re.match(pattern, row[2]).group(1)
    row[2] = f'({new})'

print(a)
```

output

```
[['#define' 'name_1' '(val1)']
 ['#define' 'name_2' '(val2)']
 ['#define' 'name_3' '(val3)']
 ['#define' 'name_4' '(val4)']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized one-liner without using any for loops, or nested NumPy operations. Just change the dtype for the specific column to `<U8` -

```
a[:,-1] = a[:,-1].astype('<U8')   #<----

print(a)
```

```
array([['#define', 'name_1', '(value1)'],
       ['#define', 'name_2', '(value2)'],
       ['#define', 'name_3', '(value3)'],
       ['#define', 'name_4', '(value4)']], dtype='<U22')
```

---

Technically speaking, for your example, since your other strings are less than length 8, you could just use `a.astype('<U8')` but be careful while applying to the complete array.

```
a.astype('<U8')
```

```
array([['#define', 'name_1', '(value1)'],
       ['#define', 'name_2', '(value2)'],
       ['#define', 'name_3', '(value3)'],
       ['#define', 'name_4', '(value4)']], dtype='<U8')
```

But note, this will apply an 8-length restriction to all the other cells.